# Is there anyway to deploy 2 django projects using docker having different domain?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, deployment, multiple-domains

I am new to programming world, so basically an average. Since few days, I am beating myself up in order to deploy 2 django projects having different domains with docker, uwsgi and Nginx but somehow I could not.
Problem 1: I cant run 2nd nginx docker using port 80. Getting an error of port already in use.
Problem 2: If I change the ports and run the app docker and nginx. It doesnt work. Both the domains pointing to Nginx at port 80. As per nginx logs.
Problem 3: One domain that is mentioned in allowed hosts of django settings, works fine. And other domain throws a bad request error. Same thing on Vice-versa.

I have read multiple articles saw multiple posts and videos still no help. So Ends up deploying the projects directly on the server using nginx and uswgi. I like the docker technology but had to stop it. There's not much relevant topics available in internet. So asking here with minimum to no hope.
Am I missing something?
Any points and help relevant to this topic would be appreciated?
Thanks in advance

/default.conf

```
server {
    listen ${LISTEN_PORT}; 
     server_name example.com; 


    location / {
        uwsgi_pass              ${APP_HOST}:${APP_PORT};             
        include                 /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        client_max_body_size    10M;
    
    }
    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }
}
```

Same configuration of 2nd docker app with different app and port

Nginx docker file

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1-alpine
LABEL maintainer="example.com"

COPY ./default.conf.tpl /etc/nginx/default.conf.tpl
COPY ./uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params

COPY ./run.sh /run.sh

ENV APP_PORT=9000
ENV APP_HOST=app

ENV LISTEN_PORT=80



USER root

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static && \
    chmod 755 /vol/static && \
    touch /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    chown nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    chmod +x /run.sh

VOLUME /vol/static

USER nginx

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

Comment: i think what you are looking for is an additional docker nginx container running in front as reverse proxy exposing 443 and 80 and forwarding to your indiv. servers at 8080, 8081, 8082 or similar.

Comment: Hi,@Razenstein Thanks for reply, I already tried using different container but every domain is pointing to only one nginx container having port 80. In development it works fine in localhost:8081, 8082 but problem starts in production.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out. What I did is I created a network specifying subnets like 10.5.6.0/24 and assigning ipv4 address to each container. Then I used Nginx as a reverse proxy for each project. Docker networks is the way to go. I don't know how feasible is this but works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).